# How do you convert a .jpg to .png in C++ on Windows 8?

Tags: c++, windows-8, png, jpeg

I've been looking at `BitmapDecoder` and `BitmapEncoder`, but I can't figure how to get the data from the jpg decoder to the png encoder.  The only close thing I've found is `BitmapEncoder::CreateForTranscodingAsync()` but that is for when both image formats are the same.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the ImageMagick library?

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Theres a C++ API ...  [inthe documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html) I found this in a 2 minute search:

```
#include  
using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick; 
int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
  InitializeMagick(*argv);

  // Read GIF file from disk 
  Image image( "giraffe.gif" );
  // Write to BLOB in JPEG format 
  Blob blob; 
  image.magick( "JPEG" ) // Set JPEG output format 
  image.write( &blob );

  [ Use BLOB data (in JPEG format) here ]

  return 0; 
}
```

Personally, I can recommend this library having worked rather extensively with ImageMagick (although with the C API...)

Edit: You can write the image to a memory blob and pass the bytes to the encoder...

Answer (score 2):

You can read the pixel data and write them to a BitmapEncoder using a given image format (codec) like this (sorry, that's C# and not C++, but it should work):

```
const string sourceFileName = "42.jpg";
StorageFolder imageFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFile imageFile = await imageFolder.GetFileAsync(sourceFileName);

using (IRandomAccessStream imageStream = await imageFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
  // Read the pixel data
  BitmapDecoder bitmapDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
  BitmapTransform dummyTransform = new BitmapTransform();
  PixelDataProvider pixelDataProvider = await bitmapDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
     BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, dummyTransform,
     ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
     ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
  byte[] pixelData = pixelDataProvider.DetachPixelData();

  // Save the pixel data as PNG
  const string resultImageFileName = "42.png";
  StorageFile resultImageFile =
     await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
     resultImageFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
  using (IRandomAccessStream resultImageStream =
     await resultImageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
  {
     BitmapEncoder bitmapEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(
        BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, resultImageStream);
     bitmapEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
        bitmapDecoder.OrientedPixelWidth, bitmapDecoder.OrientedPixelHeight, 
        96, 96, pixelData);
     await bitmapEncoder.FlushAsync();
  }
}
```

The only question is how to determine the best settings for the pixel format, alpha mode and DPI regarding the file format (in this case PNG). I determined the pixel mode from an existing PNG file. BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore is set because JPEG does not support transparency. Therefore it would not make sense to enable the alpha channel in the PNG file. Width and height are set to OrientedPixelWidth and OrientedPixelHeight of the BitmapDecoder because I enabled EXIF orientation when reading. DPI is set best regarding the target system. 96 is default for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Windows-8 programming, but just looking at the docs, isn't that as simple as this?

```
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream("myimage.jpg" ...);
JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
FileStream stream = new FileStream("myimage.png", FileMode.Create);
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Interlace = PngInterlaceOption.Off;
encoder.Frames.Add(bitmapSource);
encoder.Save(stream);
```

Comment: Those classes are not available for Windows Store apps.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
BitmapDecoder::GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat, BitmapAlphaMode, BitmapTransform, ExifOrientationMode, ColorManagementMode)
```

then

```
BitmapEncoder::SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat pixelFormat, BitmapAlphaMode alphaMode, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, double dpiX, double dpiY, array<unsigned char>^ pixels)
```